# Why aren't the images of an inlineformset_factory being saved?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have two models: `Profile` and `CredentialImage`.

I am trying to allow each Profile to upload, optionally, up to 5 maximum images(CredentialImage).
I've decided to use an inlineformset_factory for the images because on the UpdateView users will be given the option of updating their general Profile information as well as their 5 select images.

The code goes without error, but the images do not save to the database.

Here are the two models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("profile:profile_detail",
                       kwargs={"username": self.user})

class CredentialImage(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, default=None)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=credential_photo_upload_loc)
```

The modelforms + initialization of the inlineformset_factory:

```
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory

class ProfileUpdateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
            "introduction",
            "biography",
        ]

class CredentialImageForm(ModelForm):
    image = ImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = CredentialImage
        fields = ['image', ]

CredentialImageFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Profile,
    CredentialImage, fields=('image', ), extra=4)
```

A class-based UpdateView for updating a Profile:

```
class ProfileUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    form_class = ProfileUpdateForm
    template_name = 'profile/profile_edit.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProfileUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['credential_image'] = CredentialImageFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            context['credential_image'] = CredentialImageFormSet()
        return context

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user_profile = self.kwargs.get('username')
        obj = get_object_or_404(Profile, user__username=user_profile)
        return obj

    def form_valid(self, form):    
        data = self.get_context_data()
        formset = data['credential_image']
        if formset.is_valid():
            self.object = form.save()
            formset.instance = self.object
            formset.save()
            return redirect(self.object.get_absolute_url())

        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(ProfileUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

I'm especially wary of the `get_context_data` and `form_valid`.
Is it correct to try and instantiate the formset using `get_context_data` and to save both within `form_valid`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `request.FILES` to the formset as well as `request.POST` when you are uploading files:

```
context['credential_image'] = CredentialImageFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
```

The `get_context_data` method is meant for getting the context for the data. You shouldn't be instantiating formsets there. You could have a look at the [`UpdateWithInlinesView`](https://django-extra-views.readthedocs.io/en/latest/views.html#createwithinlinesview-and-updatewithinlinesview) from django-extra-views.